# \nonumber but keep the count

Tags: numbering, align, tags

I want to number some lines in an `align` environment (or `align*` and use `\numberthis` (see below)) but keeping the same number as if all lines were numbered.

I know I'm not clear so here is an example :

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
    A & = & 1 \notag\\
    B & = & 2 
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Here, the second line has the number 1 but I want the number 2.

(`\numberthis`, thanks its creator, I don't remember who)

```
\newcommand\numberthis{\stepcounter{equation}{1}\tag{\theequation}}
```

EDIT: If I had another system, I want the counter starts again with 1. For instance, for the code below, I want two number 2 (and maybe, a number for the system itself to be able to say: the 2nd equation for the system one is blabla)

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand\nonumberthis{\refstepcounter{equation}\nonumber}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
    A & = & 1 \nonumberthis\\
    B & = & 2 
\end{align}

\begin{align}
    A & = & 1 \nonumberthis\\
    B & = & 2 
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Readers will look for number 1. What's the reason for omitting it?

Comment: You can use `\newcommand\nonumberthis{\refstepcounter{equation}\nonumber}`.

Comment: you could do this, but really it will just confuse anyone reading the document.

Comment: Thanks.
I want do that for two reasons : first know in one look how many equations I have (number the last one), I think it's important when you have about 50 equations to be sure you don't forget one equation. (It wasn't explained here).
The second reason is the document is mainly for me (and two people I work with) and I feel confuse to see the second equation with the number 1.

Comment: I understand the problem : If I had another system, the counter doesn't start at 1.
I want to have a counter which is relativ to every system. (maybe it's clearer in the EDIT)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question has two parts:

- You want to omit the number for a line in your equation, but still count this line in the numbering of all lines. As suggested in the comments, define a command that increases the `equation` counter by 1 and calls the `\nonumber` macro:

  ```
  \newcommand\nonumberthis{\refstepcounter{equation}\nonumber}
  ```
- You want to number the lines in each `align` block starting from 1. In other words, you want to reset the `equation` counter to 0 at the start of every `align` environment. You can achieve this easily with the macro `\AtBeginEnvironment` from the `etoolbox` package:

  ```
  \usepackage{etoolbox}
  \AtBeginEnvironment{align}{\setcounter{equation}{0}}
  ```

Full example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\AtBeginEnvironment{align}{\setcounter{equation}{0}}
\newcommand\nonumberthis{\refstepcounter{equation}\nonumber}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
    a&=1 \nonumberthis \\
    b&=2 \\
    c&=3 \nonumberthis
\end{align}

\begin{align}
    \alpha&=1 \\
    \beta&=2 \nonumberthis \\
    \gamma&=3
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]